# How do I configure Azure Dev Ops to release my code to Azure based on the branch?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have recently started using Azure Dev Ops to manage the code of my ASP.NET Core Web Application.  I followed the Microsoft online guides for setting up Azure Dev Ops, but, the tutorials are basic and assume that you're always pushing to production through your pipeline.  In my organisation, that's not the case and I am looking for some guidance and clarification on my process and how it can be achieved.

**My Scenario**

My project has two branches `master` and `staging`.  The `staging` branch has all the feature I'm working on that need to be tested by selected users in my organisation, once those features are tested they are merged into the master branch and pushed to production for use.

**What have I done so far?**

- I have created a pipeline for CI/CD that builds and releases every time the `master` branch is synced.
- I have created slots on my Azure web app, one for `production` and one for `staging`.

**What do I need help with?**

- I need to understand how I deploy the changes I make to my `staging` branch to my web app `staging` slot in Azure so that people can test the new features.
- How do I use these branch filters that I've seen?
- Is it better to use the filters or triggers?

**What do I know?**

- I've seen that there are tags and filters that can be used but I'm lost on how they would apply to what I need to achieve.
- I attempted to put a stage in my release that pushed the project to the staging slot in my web app, the problem with that is that it's always the master branch and I don't want to release features for testing on the master branch.

[image: This is ok, but it uses the master branch]

I'm sure it's a simple setup, but I'm struggling to get it locked down.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add another CI pipeline to build your staging branch, so you have a CI pipeline for every branch you want to build. This makes it easier tdd additional steps for production if needed. On the CD pipeline you can also create a pipeline for each branch, you can select the artifacts of each CI pipeline and add a deployment trigger for the responsive branches.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need separate CI/CD pipelines. However, FWIW, you shouldn't have separate branches here anyways. The master branch is your deployment branch, having a staging branch makes no sense because staging that tells you nothing about what master is going to do when deployed. You should deploy master to the staging environment, verify that it works, and then deploy master to production.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate pipeline, that triggers on changes to the stanging branch.